# Android Widget - Animate background change for remote view?

Tags: android, animation, widget

I'm changing the background color using this:

`remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_container, "setBackgroundResource", bgResource);`

I'm wondering if there's a straightforward way to animate the color change. The only thing I can think to do is use selectors as backgrounds and use the fade properties.  This, however, involves creating a lot of additional drawables, and the animation would be fading, not transitions between colors.

Thanks!